# Ajuda remover link site - Laravel

Tags: laravel

Boa tarde pessoal, peguei recentemente um projeto no Laravel.
Preciso remover um link no <$footer> e não sei por onde faço isso.
Sou iniciante no framework.

Comment: Queira ler as orientações já dadas quando perguntou da [primeira vez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/548550/70). Duplicação de postagens com os mesmos problemas atrapalha a comunidade e não é permitido. Mais informações nos links passados no quadro de fechamento da postagem original, respectivo campo de comentários e também na central de ajuda do site.